# Removing tagged object from ScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a lot of images in a scrollView, all the same, one after another, and a delete button as a subview of each. I assign a tag in this way

```
1) img.tag = i; 

2) int z;
        z = i+1;
     buttonDelete.tag = z;
```

and i is a for loop. when I press the button this code is executed:

```
-(IBAction)deleteMessage:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*) sender;
    NSLog(@"Clicked button %d", button.tag); 

    UIImageView *image = (UIImageView*) sender;
    NSLog(@"Clicked button %d", image.tag);

    int n;
    n = button.tag;

    for (UIImageView *img in imageArray)
    {
        if (img.tag == n)
        {
            [img removeFromSuperview];

            NSLog(@"The value of integer num is %i", img.tag);
            NSLog(@"The value of integer num is %i", n);
        }
    }
}
```

According to the NSLog, the first four buttons correspond exactly to their tag, and to the image tag. The corresponding image is deleted. These four images all fit in the fist view of the scroll view. If there are more images though, and I need to scroll down, the tags don't increase anymore. Instead they restart from tag 1. So 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4... and 1,2,3,4 can be seen in the same "page" of the scroll view. How can this be??

### EDIT:

I also tried this:

```
-(IBAction)deleteMessage:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*) sender;
    NSLog(@"Clicked button %d", button.tag); 

    UIImageView *image = (UIImageView*) sender;
    NSLog(@"Clicked button %d", image.tag);

    int n;
    n = button.tag;

    for (UIImageView *img in imageArray)
    {
        if ([img isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && img.tag == n) {

            [img removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

but gives the same result

Comment: Is superview a UIScrollView or you use UITableView?

Comment: That's weird. Could you please add to the question full code of creation images and how you add them to scrollview?

Comment: Why are you casting `sender` to `UIButton` and then to `UIImageView`? That seems wrong. Also, from what you wrote it's not clear that `z' is initialized at all in the beginning.